# SQL - find id / "x_id" of rowset with maximum number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Having trouble with a (my)sql question...

I have data like:

```
id | x_id | bar
1  | 14a  | foo
2  | 15a  | baz
3  | 14a  | bim
4  | 15a  | bog
5  | 14a  | bit
```

The result I'm looking for is just 14a, where it is chosen because there are the most rows with 14a as x_id

Comment: `count(), order by ... desc, limit 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x_id, COUNT(*) as RecordCount
FROM
   TableName
GROUP BY
   x_id
ORDER BY
   COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select x_id
from t
group by x_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works:

select x_id, count(x_id) c from tbl group by x_id order by c DESC ;